# Kendo UI MVC how to change the selector before rendering

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, kendo-ui

I'm using *Kendo UI MVC Wrappers* and I have a code like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()                                                  
    .Name("MyField_Something")
 )
```

and it produces an html that looks something like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" tabindex="0" style="" unselectable="on">
    <script>
        jQuery(function(){jQuery("#MyField_Something").kendoDropDownList();});
    </script>
    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="MyField.Something"></span>
</div>
```

My question is, is it possible to change the **selector** of that *jQuery* script before the kendo renders it? Instead of just the **id**, I would like to have its **parent element** also like this:

```
<script>
        jQuery(function(){jQuery("#ParentElement #MyField_Something").kendoDropDownList();});
</script>
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: This isn't possible. Why would you want to do it anyway?

Comment: You're right. Not possible..:/

Comment: @JudeDuran Did you come up with a solution?
I would ask the same question. It is needed because of possible multiple modal popup elements in the page. 

Consider a scenario that i am opening popup "div" elements from the same PartialView with Ajax requests. And the partial view response includes kendo components inside. There will be multiple input elements with the same "id" attributes. And kendo fails to initialize the elements in the second window content. 

It would be nice, if i was able to modify the jQuery selector before initialization.

Comment: That was also my dilemma. Unfortunately, I didn't find any answer using this method. So I just named my controls uniquely by adding prefix on their IDs. :/